# How can I use email templates in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, email-templates

I want to send emails automatically when certain events happen in my .Net API.

Now I have some email templates in my database which look something like these:

First Template:

```
$"Hi, {userName}, Thanks for joining us."
```

Second Template:

```
$"Hi, {userName}, Welcome to our website."
```

When some event occurs, I want to fill up the variables with actual values and then send the email. what is the best way to do so? considering that we only know what the string wants but not the string itself.

Comment: string.Replace? You seem to have enough control over the templates to keep it pretty simple.

Comment: @nbk both yes and no. These packages that the best answer is referring to are good but probably lack long-term support, and aren't a long-term solution. however, thanks for your recommendation. It gave me some direction to look for similar things.

Comment: @Ralf, I do, but on the other hand. my customers provide the templates. If the templates have a change in their variables and I change the model which I use to fill up those variables there would be no refactoring. but with string.Replace there won't be enough flexibility and I would need to change what has to be replaced.

Comment: string.Replace still seems the best easiest option available. Communicate the allowed placeholder to your customer. And maybe add checks that only known placeholders are used. I would even consider a tool that uses a template and shows the replaced result (with some testdata) when there isn't something between creating of the template by the user and using the template in the system already.